# How to place the labels further from pie chart

Tags: r, pie-chart

How to place the labels further away from pie chart in R?

```
slices <- c(10, 12, 4, 16, 8)
lbls <- c("US", "UK", "Australia", "Germany", "France")
pct <- round(slices/sum(slices)*100)
lbls <- paste(lbls, pct) # add percents to labels
lbls <- paste(lbls,"%",sep="") # ad % to labels
pie(slices,labels = lbls, col=rainbow(length(lbls)), radius=.2)
```

[image: pie chart example]

Comment: Just don't use pie-charts. A bar-plot is much more informative.

Comment: Do you mean there is no way? This is just an example... I'm using the pie chart just for the legend of a [stars](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/stars.html) chart, but I still want to format the pie chart.

Comment: There is probably a way to do this, but pie-charts are just a very bad way of visualizing data.

Comment: Just remember this advice: http://klmr.me/pie/

Comment: Nice one! As I said I'm using mainly the **[stars chart](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/stars.html)**. The pie chart is just my legend...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can modify the `pie`-function line `50-54` and save it as a new function `pie2`

Type

```
pie
```

Change line `50-54` to

```
if (!is.na(lab) && nzchar(lab)) {
  lines(c(1, 1.35) * P$x, c(1, 1.35) * P$y)
  text(1.5 * P$x, 1.5 * P$y, labels[i], xpd = TRUE, 
       adj = ifelse(P$x < 0, 1, 0), ...)
}
```

Change line length (default = `1.05`)

```
  lines(c(1, 1.35) * P$x, c(1, 1.35) * P$y)
```

Change the factor (default = `1.1`)

```
  text(1.5 * P$x, 1.5 * P$y, labels[i], xpd = TRUE, 
       adj = ifelse(P$x < 0, 1, 0), ...)
```

Now define `pie2` and run the new function

```
pie2(slices,labels = lbls, col=rainbow(length(lbls)), radius=.2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You could manually place text with text() and create no labels by rep("",times).

But I agree, pie-charts are a bad way to visualize data.

To provide some code,

```
pie(slices,labels = rep("",5), col=rainbow(length(lbls)), radius=.8,lty=4)
text(0.9,0.6,"UK")
lines(c(0.6,0.85),c(0.45,0.55))
```

and align everything where you want it.

If you just want to create one single pie chart this is an option, but getting all those coordinates right can be very frustrating..

Sorry I would have commented rather then answered if I had the option.

Comment: Almost, but the answers is only acceptable if I can calculate the positions of the text and the linepoints...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ggplot` to form the pie-chart. This will get the labels separate from the pie-chart as a legend.

```r
# R version 3.2.2
install.packages("ggplot2") 
library("ggplot2")
slices <- c(10, 12, 4, 16, 8)
lbls <- c("US", "UK", "Australia", "Germany", "France")
pct <- round(slices/sum(slices)*100)
lbls <- paste(lbls, pct) # add percents to labels
lbls <- paste(lbls,"%",sep="") # ad % to labels
df = data.frame(slices = slices,labels =  lbls)
ggplot(df,aes(x = factor(1),fill = labels))+
        geom_bar(width = 1)+
        coord_polar(theta = "y")+
        theme(axis.title = element_blank())
```

[image: ggplot output]

Comment: That was actually not the question... See the correct answer from [@harre](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33260393/3001970). But thanks for the try.

Comment: These pie slices look like they are the same size -- not the percentages represented in the legend